# Tensorflow Prediction with LSTM

Tags: tensorflow, lstm, prediction, multi-step

I have a question about predicting multiple steps into the future with an LSTM net in Tensorflow.
I know and understood the possibility of predicting one step into the future and than adding the predicted value to the input of the next step like shown below:
[image: prediction_option_1]
I have also found some information on predicting all the neccessary steps into the future at once like so:
[image: prediction_option_2]
I just coundn't figure out if this second option actually works and if so how the implementation works in tensorflow. I would be grateful if somebody knew this and could shed some light on it for me.
Also if anyone has tried which approach works better would be great to know as well.
Thx LIZ.